# Need to center a radio button inside an inline-block

Tags: html, css

I want to center a radio button inside an inline-block. I have a fiddle that shows you what I have now and how I want it to look.

https://jsfiddle.net/ut522fca/

Code currently looks like this:

```
  <span style="width: 45px; height: 45px; margin:auto; display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; border-radius: 2px; background: #006884"><input type="radio" name="Color" id="radio" value="006884"></span>
```

Comment: just use this code `span{
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 45px;
}`. By the way, don't write a lot of inline css to style element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<span style="width: 45px; height: 45px; line-height: 45px; text-align: center; margin:auto; display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; border-radius: 2px; background: #006884"><input type="radio" name="Color" id="radio" value="006884"></span>
```

```html
  <span style="width: 45px; height: 45px; line-height:45px; text-align:center; margin:auto; display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; border-radius: 2px; background: #006884"><input type="radio" name="Color" id="radio" value="006884"></span>
  <span style="width: 45px; height: 45px; line-height:45px; text-align:center; margin:auto; display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; border-radius: 2px; background: #00909E"><input type="radio" name="Color" id="radio" value="00909E"></span>
  <span style="width: 45px; height: 45px; line-height:45px; text-align:center; margin:auto; display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; border-radius: 2px; background: #89DBEC"><input type="radio" name="Color" id="radio" value="89DBEC"></span>
  <br>
 <br>

        <p>I would like it to look like the boxes below with the radio button in the center without using a table.</p>        
  <table cellpadding="10">
    <tr>
      <td bgcolor="#006884"><input type="radio" name="Color" id="radio" value="006884"></td>
      <td bgcolor="#00909E"><input type="radio" name="Color" id="radio2" value="00909E"></td>
      <td bgcolor="#89DBEC"><input type="radio" name="Color" id="radio3" value="89DBEC"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: You just need to add "line-height:45px; text-align:center;" on each Span element

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS file

```
#radio{
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}

span{
    position:relative;
}
```

For inline : Use the below code instead.

```
<span style="width: 45px; position:relative; height: 45px; margin:auto; display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; border-radius: 2px; background: #006884"><input type="radio" name="Color" id="radio" style="margin: 0; position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);" value="006884"></span>
```